# wordpress Search function is not working

Tags: plugins, functions, plugin-recommendation, search, function-exists

My wordpress Website Version is 2.8.1,This is the Custom wordpress website done by 2 years ago.[Link Removed... i got Solution][1]Now Search functionality is not working(It was working well earlier.)
My Client told **Don't Upgrade the Version**. so here we need to replace the old search function with newer Search function.

My **searchform.php**

```
 <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" style="padding-bottom:30px;">
<input type="search" value="search..." name="s" id="s" class="inputbox" onblur="this.value='search...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='search...') this.value='';" /> <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />
</form>
```

There is no more Files like "**search.php"** . 
I don't know how to replace the older search function with newer one.So please any one guide me.
or any search plugin is do this work.

Thanks in advance.

This Thread is Closed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just to clarify your question. Your problem is with the search form not appearing in the top right corner? All I see there is a search image, but no input field. The search functionality does work on your site, eg: http://lunetours.com/?s=destination but something's not configured properly there either, as it's not returning any results.

Now, as to why your search form is not appearing, there's not enough code or information to figure this out. Have you tried turning on WP("debug") in wp-config.php?

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Comment: Sorry @:ZweiBlumen , am working on it,so only you got like no input field.Now i undo it.Please Check and give your valuable reply.

Comment: The input field works now, but the search brings back no results for terms which should probably have a match.